# Rails group_by showing multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a page showing events grouped by month and sorted by the event date.

**events_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @events = Event.all.order("date DESC")
  @event_months = @events.group_by { |t| t.date.beginning_of_month }
end
```

**_event.html.erb**

```
<% @event_months.each do |month, events| %>
  <h2><%= month.strftime('%B') %></h2>
  <% for event in events %>
    <div class="events">
      <%= event.name %>
      <%= format_date(event.date) %>
      <%= event.description %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have five events in my database. Opening the event `index.html`, I can see one event in May, two in April, two in March. This is repeated four times; it's repeating the loop as often as there are events in the database, I guess.

What do I need to do so that each event is only shown once?

Here is the `index.html.erb` that renders the partial:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Events</h1>
  <div class="row">
      <%= render @events %>
  </div>
  <div class="row event-row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 neues-event">
          <%= link_to 'Neues Event erstellen', new_event_path, class: "btn btn-default center-block" %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related, but you should almost never need to use `for` loop. `events.each do |event|` is more idiomatic way. Now, how to you render `_event` partial? Please show index template.

Comment: Hey @BroiSatse. Thanks for the note. I've been using a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month) example to create this where they are using a `for` loop to get to their result. I've shared the index template in my initial question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using:

```
 <%= render @events %>
```

Rails is iterating all of your events and rendering the **_event.html.erb** partial each time.

You could try placing the **event_months** code in its own partial, in the index.html.erb, or in another location.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Simple answer to a question that caused me a massive headache today.